# How to get JSON Using ASP.net Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.Net web api and SQl-Server as my Backend.
my sql gives me data which i store in datatable.

How can i return json from my API to my client side app(angularjs)?

*I am new to asp.net webapi.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Web API` call will return `application/json` by default, so you won't need to explicitly set the response type.

Why are you storing in a `DataTable`?

If you use a tool like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), you can make requests to your API and inspect the JSON that's returned.

You will find some good tutorials here [Learn Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Answer (score -1):

> Actions, in WebAPI, return a raw object. Web API will automatically
>   convert it into a structured response in the desired format (like JSON
>   or XML) using a feature of Web API called Content Negotiation.
>   (Wrox Professional ASP.NET MVC4)

When your AngularJS code makes a call to WebAPI, WebAPI automatically determines the return type and returns data in appropriate  format.

For more information, see this [blog post](http://harouny.com/2013/02/03/using-angularjs-to-consume-webapi-service-in-mvc4-project/)

Comment: Actions in Web API can either return a HttpResponseMessage or a CLR object to be serialized by a formatter.  This may sound pedantic but Web API doesn't have "a feature called Content Negotiation". HTTP does.  Web API just happens to have an implementation of that feature.  The reason I mention this is that it is important that people learn how HTTP works and then use Web API to build stuff.  Not just learn Web API.